# How can I load a variable in head title in Nuxt3 using useHead?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I want to load a variable in the title in the head in Nuxt3.

Can someone explain how it works?

I tried with useHead and useAsyncData. (jobData is a variable from useAsyncData and it's undefined)

```
useHead({
    title: route.params.job.replace('-', ' '),
    // titleTemplate: "%s - test"
    meta: [
        { name: 'description', content: `${route.params.job.replace('-', ' ')} - Lorem ipsum` },
        { name: 'keywords', content: jobData.value.values.map(x => ` ${x}`) }
    ],
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Call the useHead() composable after the variable is loaded.

For example.

```
async function loadValue() {
    const response = await useAsyncData("some-endpoint-")
    value = response.data
    useHead({
       title: `${value}`
    })
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -2):

In your page you can add something like this:

```js
<script>
const title = 'some value'
definePageMeta({
  title: `Page Title - ${title}`,
})
</script>
```

See: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/utils/define-page-meta/

Comment: where does the 'some value' come from?

Comment: No where, it's just a string you can assign to a variable